# Confusion about how $A$ is equal to its successor when $A$ is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the set theory text I am reading, J. Donald Monk's *Introduction to Set Theory*, it is stated (p.20):

> If $A$ is a proper class, then $\mathcal{S}(A) = A$

where $\mathcal{S}(A) := \{ x : x \in A \vee x = A \}$, and is called the *successor* of $A$.

The provided proof is essentially as follows.

> 1. Assume that $X$ is any class. If $X ∈ A$, then $X$ is a set and either:
>      $X \in A$   or   $X = A$.  Hence, $X \in  \mathcal{S}(A)$.
> 2. If $X \in \mathcal{S}(A)$, then $X \in A$  or $X = A$, and $X$ is a set; 
>      since $A$ is not a set, the possibility $X = A$ is excluded, so that we
>      always have $X \in A$.
> 3. Thus $(\forall X) [X \in \mathcal{S}(A) \Leftrightarrow  X \in A]$  and so that by the axiom of extensionality, $\mathcal{S}(A) = A$.

I am confused about step (1). Given a class $C$, if $x$ is an element 
of $\mathcal{S}(C)$, must it be true that either

1. $x$ is an element of $C$  (this seems obvious), or
2. $x = C$  (this seems very non-obvious)?

On the other hand, when I consider that $A = \{A\}$  is legal for a class, but not a set, and then when I am given  the statement   $X \in A$, and I am also told $A$ is a proper class (which cannot be an element of any other set or class), then I guess I do understand that, in this case,  $X$ must be equal to $A$.

Given what I wrote on the last paragraph, maybe I actually do understand this?

---

Epilogue:
The Elvis Presley analogy (from Arthur's comment) turned on the light bulb for me.   First.. I checked and Elvis is indeed dead, so what Arthur did was point out  that the true/falseness of a statement 'S' is not changed if  we say

*S OR something-known-to-be-false*

The *something-known-to-be-false* in step 1  was X = A  (stated right after we said $X ∈ A$, which means that no way can X=A).  I understand (finally) why the known-not-to-be-true thing was tacked on.  It was tacked on so that we could state that  $X \in  \mathcal{S}(A)$ to feed in to the argument that follows.

Comment: Remember that "or" in mathematics is inclusive; if $x \in C$, then "$x \in C\text{ or Elvis Presley is still alive}$" is true.

Comment: The successor of a class is the collection of sets *belonging* to that class or *equal* to that class.  Since a proper class isn't a set, the second case can't happen: its successor is just the collection of sets *belonging* to it, i.e., the proper class itself.

Comment: Arthur - thanks a million... if you make your comment an answer i will happily accept ;^)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mjqxxxx. The reason is that the definition uses a naive but nevertheless set based class builder, i.e. the variable x is lower case and therefore stands for a set. But a proper class is not a set, so that x=A never succeeds, and then you have S(A)=A.

See also this theorem here:
**A proper class is its own successor**
http://at.metamath.org/mpegif/sucprc.html

If you would have classes of classes, and use a different class builder, you would also get a different successor of a class, with S(A)<>A. But this successor is not a class anymore, so I guess things would get pretty contrieved, at last not [simply typed](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#2) anymore.